# Concepts I need to learn to make a simple search box

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Well, I have a simple page displaying records from Database with PHP & MySQL. I want to make a simple search box to search through the displayed records on the page. I want to do this preferably using Jquery & I am a total newbie to jQuery. What concepts do I need to know in order to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a good plugin from jquery, I used the following before it works prefectly.

http://lomalogue.com/jquery/quicksearch/

I hope it helps